# Cards Lists React Material

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a very simple problem. I wanted to make a lists of cards from left to right. My problem is that the card is on the center right now and when i add another card it adds up below. I wanted it to be like from left to right.

Pls see this codesandbox link

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fejru?file=/demo.js)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "initial"
  },
  title: {
    marginBottom: "30px"
  },
  header: {
    marginBottom: "20px",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  card: {
    maxWidth: 300,
    margin: "auto",
    transition: "0.3s",
    boxShadow: "0 8px 40px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)",
    "&:hover": {
      boxShadow: "0 16px 70px -12.125px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"
    }
  },
  media: {
    paddingTop: "56.25%"
  },
  content: {
    textAlign: "left",
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  },
  divider: {
    margin: `${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px 0`
  },
  heading: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  subheading: {
    lineHeight: 1.8
  },
  avatar: {
    display: "inline-block",
    border: "2px solid white",
    "&:not(:first-of-type)": {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit
    }
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material UI has a pretty sweet grid implementation via the [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) component. Just wrap your cards in a `<Grid container>` like so:

```
  <Grid container>
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      ...
    </Card>
  </Grid>
```

[Updated sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-777kw)

Comment: What if there is only two cards? Can you make second one go to the left side? There is much space between the first and second card. Make it align to the add button too Thanks

Comment: Is the card number going to be static? Are there going to be only two cards at all times or will it vary?

Comment: It will vary. The card is dynamic

Comment: This was caused bu the `margin: "auto"` in the `card` style. What is more, if you wish to have padding between the cards, `<Grid>` component has a `spacing` prop that you can use. I've updated the code sandbox slightly. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-777kw?file=/demo.js

Comment: Great! Can you add an additional card so i can see how it looks?

Comment: Great! Can you add an additional card so i can see how it looks